# react-native Linking.getInitialURL doesn't return query parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, deep-linking

Following the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/linking/#linking-module) you can use the method `Linking.getInitialURL` to get which URL the app was opened with (e.g. if opened from a web browser) as follow:

```
// called from exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc
export default function App(props) {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log('Initial url is: ' + url);
      // 'Initial url is exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc'
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  return (<AppNavigator />);
}
```

The above works correctly, however **I can't manage to retrieve query parameters** added to the url using the snippet below

```
// called with exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc?test=1234
export default function App(props) {
  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    if (url) {
      let { path, queryParams } = Linking.parse(url);
      // path: exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc
      // queryParams: null
    }
  }).catch(err => console.error('An error occurred', err));
  return (<AppNavigator />);
}
```

Moreover if I try to `console.log(url)` I get the input url without the `?test=1234`, so it looks like is getting discarded by the Linking module.

Comment: for anyone stuck on this, a workaround is instead of putting the params in query params `exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc?test=1234` you can put it in the path and later parse it `exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc/--/1234`, you can read more here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a solution which worked for me:

Instead of calling with 'exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc?test=1234', perhaps you can try calling it with "exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc/**index.exp**?test=1234"

Note:
The link i tried with redirected me to an Expo app (SDK 37.0.0) that was published (not built).
Also, just merely using 'exp://expo.io/@solbiatialessandro/GettingIntoYc?test=1234' works when tested with an IOS device, however it could not work with an Android device.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Its weird but this worked for me

```
let newURL = Linking.parse(url);
console.log(newURL.queryParams);
```

Comment: What is `Linking.parse`? I don't see it in the documentation

Comment: Linking.parse doesn't work for me either..